# openam J2EE Policy agent - ServerEntryNotFoundException: Cannot find server ID

Tags: dependencies, jboss7.x, noclassdeffounderror, openam, jboss-modules

I have an openAM application running on Tomcat 7.
On my JBoss server, which has an application protected by OpenAM, I get the following error message when accessing any protected resource:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmFilterManager
    at com.sun.identity.agents.filter.AmAgentBaseFilter.initializeFilter(AmAgentBaseFilter.java:270) [agent.jar:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT - 20140502-0259]
    ... 16 more
```

This class belongs to the Web Policy agent that I installed on my Jboss which created a [jboss module](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Home) which declares these dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
      <module name="javax.servlet.api" />
      <module name="javax.api" />
      <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" />
      <module name="javax.ejb.api" />
      <module name="org.picketbox" />
    </dependencies>
```

But I've checked my *jboss/modules* directory for these dependencies and they're all there.

In my [Web Policy agent's](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam-pa/3.1.0-Xpress/agent-install-guide/index/chap-about-web-agents.html) log file, I see this being logged every minute:

```
ERROR: WebtopNaming.getServerId():serverId null for server: http://openam.example.com:8181/openam
amNaming:12/04/2014 03:55:37:027 PM CET: Thread[SystemTimer,5,main]
ERROR: WebtopNaming.getServerId()
com.iplanet.services.naming.ServerEntryNotFoundException: Cannot find server ID.
    at com.iplanet.services.naming.WebtopNaming.getServerID(WebtopNaming.java:757)
    at com.iplanet.services.naming.WebtopNaming.getServerID(WebtopNaming.java:654)
    at com.iplanet.services.naming.WebtopNaming$SiteMonitor.checkAvailableSiteList(WebtopNaming.java:1738)
    at com.iplanet.services.naming.WebtopNaming$SiteMonitor.runCheckValidSite(WebtopNaming.java:1713)
    at com.iplanet.services.naming.WebtopNaming$SiteMonitor.run(WebtopNaming.java:1706)
    at com.sun.identity.common.TimerPool$WorkerThread.run(TimerPool.java:434)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when I created my default configuration after installing openAM, I had accessed the openAM server via *localhost:8181* instead of *openam.example.com:8181*.

So openAM automatically created a Server configuration with the name *localhost:8181/openam*. These configurations can be found on the admin console under Configuration > Servers and sites.

Comment: You should never install OpenAM with "localhost", at least you should fake an FQDN for it using /etc/hosts entries.

Comment: Can you tell me where does OpenAM store its configuration? I think I'm in a similar situation (and I can't access the UI).